# Not able to test view functions in hardhat

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy, hardforks

Solidity code

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "base64-sol/base64.sol";

error tokenURI__InvalidToken(uint256 tokenId);

contract DynamicNft is ERC721 {
    uint256 private s_tokenCounter;
    string private i_lowImageUri;
    string private i_highImageUri;
    string private constant base64EncodedPrefix = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,";
    AggregatorV3Interface internal immutable i_priceFeed;
    mapping(uint256 => int256) tokeninToHighValue;

    event CreatedNft(uint256 indexed tokenId, int256 highValue);

    constructor(
        address priceFeed,
        string memory lowSvg,
        string memory highSvg
    ) ERC721("DYNAMICNFT Nft", "DSN") {
        i_priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(priceFeed);
        s_tokenCounter = 0;
        i_lowImageUri = svgToImageUri(lowSvg);
        i_highImageUri = svgToImageUri(highSvg);
    }

    function svgToImageUri(string memory svg) public pure returns (string memory) {
        string memory svgBase64Encoded = Base64.encode(bytes(string(abi.encodePacked(svg))));
        return string(abi.encodePacked(base64EncodedPrefix, svgBase64Encoded));
    }

    function mintNft(int256 highValue) public {
        uint256 currentIndex = s_tokenCounter;
        s_tokenCounter++;
        tokeninToHighValue[currentIndex] = highValue;
        _safeMint(msg.sender, currentIndex);
        emit CreatedNft(currentIndex, highValue);
    }

    function _baseURI() internal pure override returns (string memory) {
        return "data:application/json;base64,";
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view override returns (string memory) {
        if (!_exists(tokenId)) {
            revert tokenURI__InvalidToken(tokenId);
        }
        string memory ImgUri = i_lowImageUri;
        (, int256 price, , , ) = i_priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        if (price >= tokeninToHighValue[tokenId]) {
            ImgUri = i_highImageUri;
        }
        return (
            string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    _baseURI(),
                    Base64.encode(
                        bytes(
                            abi.encodePacked(
                                '{"name":"',
                                name(),
                                '", "description":"nft changes with price of ETH",',
                                '"attributes":[{"trait_type":"cuteness","value":100}],"image":"',
                                ImgUri,
                                '"}'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }

    function getPriceFeed() public view returns (AggregatorV3Interface) {
        return i_priceFeed;
    }

    function getLowSvg() public view returns (string memory) {
        return i_lowImageUri;
    }

    function getHighSvg() public view returns (string memory) {
        return i_highImageUri;
    }
```

hardhat deploy script

```
const { networkConfig, developmentChains } = require("../helper-hardhat-config");
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify");
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments;
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();

    let ethUsdPriceFeedAddress;
    const ethUsdAggregator = await deployments.get("MockV3Aggregator");
    const chainId = network.config.chainId;
    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = ethUsdAggregator.address;
    } else {
        ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = networkConfig[chainId].ethUsdPrice;
    }
    const lowSvg = fs.readFileSync("./images/dynamicNft/sad.svg", { encoding: "utf8" });
    const highSvg = fs.readFileSync("./images/dynamicNft/smiley.svg", { encoding: "utf8" });

    const args = [ethUsdPriceFeedAddress, lowSvg, highSvg];
    const dynamicSvgNft = await deploy("DynamicNft", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    });

    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.POLYGON_API_KEY) {
        log("Verifying..........");
        await verify(dynamicSvgNft.address, args);
    }
};

module.exports.tags = ["all", "dynamicnft", "main"];
```

Test file

```
const { network, deployments, ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { developmentChains } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config");

const highSvgImageUri ="HIGH_URL"
const lowSvgImageUri ="LOW_URL"
   
!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? describe.skip
    : describe("Dynamic NFT svg tests", function () {
          let dynamicNft, MockV3Aggregator, deployer;
          beforeEach(async () => {
              accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
              MockV3Aggregator = ethers.deployContract("MockV3Aggregator");
              dynamicNft = ethers.deployContract("DynamicNft");
              deployer = accounts[0];
          });
          describe("Constructor Works", async function () {
              it("Sets string values correctly", async () => {
            
                  let lowSvgImage = await dynamicNft.getLowSvg();
                  let highSvgImage = await dynamicNft.getHighSvg();
            
                  assert.equal(lowSvgImage, lowSvgImageUri);
                  assert.equal(highSvgImage, highSvgImageUri);
              });
          });
      });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Not able to test view functions in hardhat"? They fail, they do nothing, there's an error, etc. Can you clarify what your issue?